# Main Release will crash immediately (2.79b) but experimental build 2.8 will run fine on PC

Tags: export

I Don't know where else I can ask, but my pc is freshly built, 1.5 weeks old, specs are:

i5 7600k 3.8 Ghz
16 GB Ram
1060 6GB Vram

I made sure my updates are up to date, graphics card, and OS.

2.79b will crash immediately, over and over. so i tried the 2.8 experimental build and that will open and run fine with no crashes.

If anyone has any input, or solutions. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please run blender from a terminal then post the output. Please specify your OS.

Comment: Oh, sorry, Windows 10 Home. i will attempt this when i get home today, then will get back to you guys.

Comment: Most of the crashes and problems when opening blender are due to the drivers for the GPU (graphics card). Sometimes you have to upgrade them,  but other times the drivers are buggy and using an older version is better.